# drupal_get_path() not working in subdirectories of my site

Tags: blocks

So I'm using drupal_get_path() within a block to reference an image in my themes//images directory.

And this works. At the root and all first level pages. example.com, example.com/about, etc.

However, if I am on a page such as example.com/about/csa:

Instead of continuing to output the filepath as /sites/all/... it outputs the file as //sites/all/...

This only happens when I'm in a subdirectory of the site.

Does anyone know why this might happen?

EDIT:

```
<?php $src = drupal_get_path('theme', $GLOBALS['theme']) . '/images/carrots.png'; 
echo '<img src=' . $src . ' alt="carrot background image" >'
?>
```

Comment: Post the code on how you used drupal_get_path?

Comment: Enable pathologic module and check it on in the desired filter(for example full html) and run your html code using check_markup function.

Comment: I was under the impression that pathologic was more for sitewide brokenness or for having your Drupal root somewhere other than your web root. I'll give it a shot. I've also updated my question with the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its because drupal_get_path returns relative path.

Try this:

```
<?php 
  global $base_path;
  $src = $base_path . drupal_get_path('theme', $GLOBALS['theme']) . '/imag/carrots.png'; 
  echo '<img src=' . $src . ' alt="carrot background image" >'
?>
```

**Edit with [url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) function:**

```
<?php 
  $src = url(drupal_get_path('theme', $GLOBALS['theme']) . '/imag/carrots.png'); 
  echo '<img src=' . $src . ' alt="carrot background image" >'
?>
```

Comment: Thank You. I used the pathologic module and it solved my problem. Is there a reason that one convention would be better or worse than the other?

Comment: Great! Pathlogic is definitely a good module. But I won't use it just for this minor issue. Every module brings its own set of function calls. I always try to keep the number of contributed modules at minimum. This bloats drupal less. better site performance. easier updates/upgrades. lesser bugs.